# Where do I find the dynamically-generated web service proxy serialization assembly?

Tags: c#, serialization, webservice-client

I have a client-side app (an IE plugin) that makes a call to a web service. I am occasionally getting this error on startup:

> System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\paul.nearney\AppData\Local\Temp\j8imytd-.dll'
>   because it is being used by another
>   process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
>   Int32 rights, Boolean useRights,
>   FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>   FileOptions options,
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access)    at
>   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] fileNames)    at
>   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] sources)    at
>   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] sources)    at
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParameters
>   options, String[] sources)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly
>   parent, String ns,
>   XmlSerializerCompilerParameters
>   xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[]
>   xmlMappings, Type[] types, String
>   defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence,
>   XmlSerializerCompilerParameters
>   parameters, Assembly assembly,
>   Hashtable assemblies)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[]
>   xmlMappings, Type[] types, String
>   defaultNamespace, String location,
>   Evidence evidence)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GetSerializersFromCache(XmlMapping[]
>   mappings, Type type)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[]
>   mappings, Type type)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(Type
>   type)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()
>   at MyWebService..ctor(String url)

I haven't yet found a reliable repro for this, but am assuming this error is happening because there is occasionally some contention over the dynamically-generated proxy assembly for the web service, possibly from multiple instances of IE attempting to generate/use the assembly at the same time(?)

I'm thinking I can get around this by getting VS to generate the proxy for me at compile time, but I need to be 100% sure that this assembly is getting used at runtime. I was planning to test with the solution as-is, confirm that the assembly is generated, and then recompile with VS compiling the proxy assembly, then retest, and confirm that the proxy assembly is not generated at runtime.

The only problem is, I can't find the dynamically generated proxy assembly anywhere..! I've tried:

- %temp%
- %systemroot%\temp
- Running the fusion log viewer (no mention of an aut-gen'd assembly at all)
- Running ProcessMonitor (no file access on a temp dll at all)

I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: Were you able to solve this conflict, or verify your compile-time solution? We're getting this exact same error under very similar circumstances (IE plug-in calling a webservice generates an IOException on the temp .dll).

Comment: Unfortunately not - it's on the back burner at the moment but will pick up the investigation again soon. Obviously I'm keen to hear the resolution if you get there first :)

Comment: Well, we think it was AVG. We disabled the antivirus and the error went away. For now we've had the affected user disable AVG while using our app, but we'll eventually try manually generating the proxy class to see if that works with AVG enabled. (We really don't want to have to tell people to disable their antivirus)

Comment: Interesting - I'm running AVG on my test box, so that could well be the problem for me too